# How to avoid JS minification in an external file add via requirejs-config.js?

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, xml, requirejs

I have a [custom module called Quicklink](https://github.com/rafaelstz/magento2-quicklink) it has its own JS files and external JS files too, I've added an external JS from a third-party CDN, but when I enable the JS minification in a Magento 2 clean installation, it turns all files into minified, not just my JS files, which causes issues with the external script.

```javascript
// File path: Rafaelcg/Quicklink/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            quicklink: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quicklink/2.0.0/quicklink.umd.js',
            polyfillio: 'https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=IntersectionObserver'
        }
    }
};
```

How could I avoid the minification only in the external JS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this exclude rule below in your `config.xml` file.

**File path: Rafaelcg/Quicklink/etc/config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <dev>
            <js>
                <minify_exclude>
                    <quicklink>/libs/quicklink</quicklink>
                    <polyfill>/v3/polyfill</polyfill>
                </minify_exclude>
            </js>
        </dev>
        <quicklink>
            <general>
                <active>1</active>
            </general>
        </quicklink>
    </default>
</config>
```